# What type of Twitter Card is this?

Tags: twitter

I'm assuming this is a twitter card.  I noticed that it appeared in my Twitter Feed with the entire image displayed, you can see it without having to click on it.  What kind of Twitter Card is it?  I posted a summary_large_image twitter card yesterday and it doesn't display unless someone clicks on it.

[image: Twitter Card?]

Comment: which tweet did you post? i don't see it in your feed

Comment: Sorry I deleted it...it's not ready for production yet.  I want to avoid people clicking on the bit.ly link for purposes of keeping the count accurate.

Comment: FWIW I don't see that tweet expanded as you do. I have to click on the "Expand" link to see it. From your screenshot "Collapse" would imply that it is already expanded (perhaps automatically?). I see that format only after I have clicked "Expand".

Comment: Do you have any keyboard shortcuts on? Maybe you are going down your timeline and it opens up big like this